# PHP Executables VSCode (Devsense Extension) Doesn't Work When Using Docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code

I have Devsense PHP Extension in Vscode and my project is inside the docker container.

I have service named "app" inside my docker compose but specifying php executables like this, doesn't work:

```json
"php.executables": {
    "my/sail-php8.2": "./docker/php/bin/php"
  }
```

Inside my ./docker/php/bin/php is like this:

```bash
docker compose exec app php "$@"
```

But somehow running phpunit tests by using this extensions wont work because the output keep showing this command:

```bash
php -d display_errors=on /home/erstevn/Code/pilihjurusan/api/vendor/bin/phpunit --teamcity
```

It means that my php executable path is not what they're using (they use php binary inside my linux instead).

What i'm supposed to do then?

**EDIT**

Somehow my PHP extension cannot find my customized php version inside the docker container

```bash
PHP extension started.
Couldn't resolve requested PHP version 'my/sail-php8.2' ... Using default 'php'.
Found PHP, version: 8.2.3, Xdebug: not loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that you have to define full path for the `php.executables` so I added this to the User `settings.json`

```json
"php.executables": {
    "custom-php-ver": "/home/(username)/(workspace)/api/docker/php/bin"
  }
```

and then inside your `php/bin` file:

```bash
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0)) && cd ../../ && ./vendor/bin/sail php "$@"
```

I'm using sail so that would be the php executable. Just in case you may asking what the `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` do, it's just referencing the php/bin file path that being executed.

I don't want use the `pwd` command because the Devtools PHP Extensions will execute the path relative to your home folder so the `pwd` will outputs `/home/(username)` instead